# tee-clc on Mac - get throws IllegalArgumentException: update.isFullyPopulated(setFileTimeToCheckin)

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, team-explorer-everywhere

This is the second TFSVC repository (one on AzureDevOps and one onpremise) that I try to get using tee-clc and crashes with this exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: update.isFullyPopulated(setFileTimeToCheckin)

This is the command I am trying to execute after creating the workspace and mapping it

tf get -recursive -all $/path

It starts downloading and then crashes always on a specific file.

Already opened an issue on github without luck: https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/issues/291

Does anybody have a hint? Thanks!

Comment: What is the file?

Comment: In this case is a png file, I can't recall the previous one. It does get some other png files but at some point it breaks. Same repo works just fine using tfs on Windows.